# Table input from separate .tex file

Tags: tables

I am trying to use the `\input` command to insert a table produced by STATA (statistics software). The problem is that I am unable to adjust the size of the table, I have tried `\resizebox` and other options with various errors. My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, abstracton, norsk]{scrartcl}          

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}               
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                            
\usepackage[utf8, latin1]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}


\clearpage
\begin{singlespace}

\begin{table}

\input{table}

\end{table}


\end{singlespace}

\end{document}
```

the table.tex file looks something like this:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcc} \hline
 & (1) & (2) \\
 & ACA & ACA \\
 & str\_all & str\_all \\
VARIABLES & Baseline FE & full controls \\ \hline
\vspace{4pt} & \begin{footnotesize}\end{footnotesize} & \begin{footnotesize}\end{footnotesize} \\
str\_all\_1982 & 0.0159 & 0.0234 \\
\vspace{4pt} & \begin{footnotesize}(0.0131)\end{footnotesize} & \begin{footnotesize}(0.0143)\end{footnotesize} \\
Share age>60 &  & -0.303 \\
\vspace{4pt} & \begin{footnotesize}\end{footnotesize} & \begin{footnotesize}(0.371)\end{footnotesize} \\
Constant & 0.876*** & 0.910*** \\
 & \begin{footnotesize}(0.00104)\end{footnotesize} & \begin{footnotesize}(0.0938)\end{footnotesize} \\
\vspace{4pt} & \begin{footnotesize}\end{footnotesize} & \begin{footnotesize}\end{footnotesize} \\
Observations & 118,319 & 117,831 \\
$R^2$ & 0.016 & 0.025 \\
Cohortdummies & yes & yes \\
Kommunedummies & yes & yes \\
clustering & kommune & kommune \\
Fylkesdummies & no & no \\
vgo fixed & no & no \\
komm time trend & no & no \\
fylke time trend & no & no \\
 Kommuner & 235 & 235 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\begin{footnotesize} Robust standard errors in parentheses\end{footnotesize}} \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\begin{footnotesize} *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1\end{footnotesize}} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: just put `\small \input{table}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is environment `center` that does not work inside `\resizebox`. Also it is not the best choice for centering in environment `table`, because environment `center` adds vertical space. The example locally disables environment `center` in the `table` and uses `\centering` instead. `\resizebox` is now working like expected:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\let\center\empty
\let\endcenter\relax
\centering
\resizebox{.5\width}{!}{\input{table}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Additional remark:**

- Only the latest option in `\usepackage[utf8,latin1]{inputenc}` is used, thus specifying several options does not make too much sense. If you are unsure about the encoding, take a look at package `selinput`.